# Martial Arts self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find a few questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Answer (score 7):

[Are there any Wing Chun Kungfu training dummy designs that are fit for use in a condo?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/762/are-there-any-wing-chun-kungfu-training-dummy-designs-that-are-fit-for-use-in-a)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question is okay; it's the answer that stands out. @BerinLoritsch gave an honest, experienced answer regarding the noise issues with using such a dummy in an apartment. I would like to have seen less reliance on links that seem to stand largely alone, but otherwise feel the answer makes this question worthy.

Comment: Agreed. The question wasn't bad, but was very much a "grain of sand" sort of question. The answer, on the other hand, was quite good.

Answer (score 5):

[How important is lineage when it comes to credibility or trustworthiness?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/759/how-important-is-lineage-when-it-comes-to-credibility-or-trustworthiness)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think it elicited good extended commentary that was productive.

Comment: This one provoked multiple well thought-out answers.

Comment: Definitely one of my favorite questions. It really addresses some points for public consumption that you wouldn't expect or hear unless you were actually in and practicing martial arts for some time. I also really like the [other question](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/681/15) that sparked it.

Answer (score 4):

[How useful is a grappling dummy, when you don't have a live training partner available?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/771/how-useful-is-a-grappling-dummy-when-you-dont-have-a-live-training-partner-ava)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think we need more people with direct experience using them for training to answer it, but it's a good question that should keep on giving.

Answer (score 1):

[Can I practice any of the martial arts after a hernia surgery?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/761/can-i-practice-any-of-the-martial-arts-after-a-hernia-surgery)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I really don't see how this question is productive...we have a non-practitioner asking about generic martial arts practice after surgery, who wants martial artists to give post-surgery advice? Slugster's anecdotal experience was useful, however.

Comment: A little too broad and general. Replace "martial arts" with any other physical activity, and it's not really so much about martial arts anymore.

Comment: I have a vested interest in this one as I was one of the answerers. Yes this *could* have been asked elsewhere, but I was able to provide some MA specific advice. As long as the injury/condition and its management relates to MA activity and it doesn't require specialist medical opinion then it should be okay - and I think this question fits this criteria in this particular case. Other questions might not be so lucky.

Answer (score 0):

[kicked in the sternum - tips on healing, time frame? any lingering danger?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/774/kicked-in-the-sternum-tips-on-healing-time-frame-any-lingering-danger)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: My comments about the hernia surgery question apply here as well. Few people outside of the OP will find this question useful. (And the OP might not find it useful either.)

Comment: I prefer this question to the hernia question: It's a practitioner asking about an injury they received within the context of martial arts.  I felt the essence of the question was reasonable, if not stellar.

Comment: Eh. I've never been a big fan of these type of injury questions.

Answer (score -2):

[Which kind of breath provides the most striking power?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/787/which-kind-of-breath-provides-the-most-striking-power)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this question has a number of problems. Berin did a good job salvaging an answer, but I don't think the question is productive in its current form.